# Bootstrap Custom Variable Rails SASS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass

In the **stylesheets/bootstrap** directory I have:

**_variables.scss** I have:

```
$black:                 #000 !default;
$grayDark:              #333 !default;
...
$textColor:             $grayDark !default;
```

This file is imported in the **bootstrap.scss** file:

```
// Core variables and mixins
@import "bootstrap/variables"; // Modify this for custom colors, font-sizes, etc
@import "bootstrap/mixins";
...
```

In the **stylesheets** directory I have **bootstrap_include.scss**

```
@import "bootstrap/bootstrap";
@import "bootstrap/responsive";
```

I want to override the default text to be black, so I create a custom variables file and imported it in my custom bootstrap file

**_variables_custom.scss:**

```
$black:                 #000 !default;
$textColor:             $black !default;
```

and then in **bootstrap_custom.scss**

```
@import "variables_custom";
```

Finally in the **application.css.scss**

```
*= require bootstrap_custom
*= require bootstrap_include
```

When I refresh the page, bootstrap_custom is always empty, I'm a css newbie, and why it isn't working?

Thanks

NOT SURE IF THIS IS NICE BUT I SOLVED IT USING:

my **bootstrap_custom** now includes

```
$black:                 #000 !default;
$textColor:             $black !default;
@import "bootstrap/bootstrap";
@import "bootstrap/responsive";
```

and my **application.css.scss** now only includes

```
*= require bootstrap_custom
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While we are talking about variables, there's nothing related to CSS. Variables, in this case, are used by SASS/Compass a CSS preprocessor tool, used by Rails to make the use of CSS more easy (eg. by using variables).

So when you insert your variables in a file, and let it be processed alone, it wont produce any CSS code unless you make any use of then in a valid CSS attribute.

If you want to test it, add to your bootstrap_custom.css something like:

```
body {
  background-color: $black;
}
```

And you will see your $black variable being used.

Comment: Yes I see it!! So what does this line mean "$textColor:             $black !default;"

Comment: I mean how to override the textColor in css? it is driving me nuts

Comment: seems like the best answer i've seen so far and i've looked through 4 different questions which all basically ask the same thing. but what a PITA, really i need to restate all of the rules which use this variable? geez.

Answer (score 3):

in your stylesheet, remove `!default`

that is, in your file **_variables_custom.scss** - instead of:

```
$black: #000 !default;
$textColor: $black !default;
```

use this instead:

```
$black: #000;
$textColor: $black;
```

---

`!default` is a sass variable flag that allows for reassignment before or after the `!default` is declared, with the non `!default` value always winning.

so:

```
$foo: black;
$foo: red !default;
body { background: $foo; }
```

will result in a black body background, even though red is declared after black